# Install ASP.NET MVC 4 from the Web Platform Installer

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, web-platform-installer

When I launch the installer, I see the product details of the ASP.NET MVC 4 framework.  When I click 'Install' it then gives me an Error dialog:

```
ASP.NET MVC 4 installer (Visual Studio 2010) is incompatible with Microsoft .NET Frameowrk 4.5
```

After I click Ok, It shows me the prerequisites page with "I Decline" and "I Accept" is grayed out and not clickable.

The [Software Requirements](http://www.asp.net/whitepapers/mvc4-release-notes#_Toc303253805) page says:

> The ASP.NET MVC 4 components for Visual Studio require PowerShell 2.0
>   and either Visual Studio 2010 with Service Pack 1 or Visual Web
>   Developer Express 2010 with Service Pack 1.

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: I think the error message is pretty clear. You need VS2010 and .NET 4 to install it and use it.

Comment: Huske, I have both installed, your comment isn't very constructive

Comment: Can anyone tell me where to download standalone installer to be used for asp.net mvc-4 to be installed on server.

Comment: @MuhammadAdeelZahid from here http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/confirmation.aspx?id=30683

Answer (score 14, accepted):

The [installation notes](http://www.asp.net/whitepapers/mvc4-release-notes#_Toc303253802) says:

`This release is not compatible with the .NET Framework 4.5 Developer Preview. You must uninstall the .NET 4.5 Developer Preview before installing the ASP.NET MVC 4 Beta.`

You probably have that installed, and should therefore uninstall .NET 4.5 Dev Preview.

UPDATE:
One alternative way is to only install the needed MVC 4 components using NuGet.
MVC4: [From NuGet](http://nuget.org/packages/aspnetmvc)
Web API: [ASP.NET Web API and HttpClient Available on NuGet](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/henrikn/archive/2012/02/20/asp-net-web-api-and-httpclient-available-on-nuget.aspx)

Comment: Good luck, it completely hosed my VS2010 install a while back.

Comment: I think this may be the solution, did they release a non-developer preview version? I can only find the Preview Version of 4.5

Comment: No, at this time only a developer preview is available.

Comment: Removing ALL of the .NET 4.5 developer preview items worked for me. I think there were 4 or 5 of them total, and each one takes awhile to uninstall.

Comment: In Add/Remove I don't have anything from .net 4.5 or VS 11, but still getting this error. I tried installing 4.5 and removing it, installing v4 again, but no luck. Really don't know where it detects 4.5 installation.

Comment: I already uninstalled .net 4.5 but mvc4 installer still error with message ASP.NET MVC 4 installer is incompatible with Microsoft .NET Frameowrk 4.5

Comment: After I uninstalled the developer preview, I was able to successfully install the MVC 4 beta.

Comment: New link to the latest NuGet package for ASP.NET MVC 4: http://nuget.org/packages/Microsoft.AspNet.Mvc

Answer (score 0):

I too was having this problem it would not install MVC 4, but i have managed to install it by downloading the ASP.NET MVC 4 provides a Model-View-Controller (MVC) framework for developing web applications http://www.microsoft.com/download/en/details.aspx?id=27419.

Once it has installed it will say that it was unsuccessful, but id you check your VS Studio 2010 you will be able to create and run an MVC 4 product